# Cleanup for running spec files in series in Protractor

Tags: protractor, end-to-end

I am running multiple specs using a Protractor configuration file as follows:

```
...
specs: [abc.js , xyz.js]
...
```

After `abc.js` is finished I want to reset my App to an initial state from where the next spec `xyz.js` can kick off.

Is there a well defined way of doing so in Protractor? I'm using Jasmine as a test framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different approach and it worked for me. Inside my first spec I am adding Logout testcase which logouts from the app and on reaching the log in page, just clear the cookie before login again using following:

```
browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use something like this:

```
specs: ['*.js']
```

But I recommend you to separate the specs with a suffix, such as `abc-spec.js` and `xyz-spec.js`. Thus your specs will be like this:

```
specs: ['*-spec.js']
```

This is done to avoiding the config file to be 'run'/tested if you put the config file in the same folder as your tests/spec files.

Also there is downside that the test will be run in `0 -> 9` and `A -> Z` order. E.g. `abc-spec.js` will run first then `xyz-spec.js`. If you want to define your custom execution order, you may prefix your spec files' names, for instance: `00-xyz-spec.js` and `01-abc-spec.js`.

To **restart the app**, sadly there is no common way ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1645)) but you need to work around to achieve it. Use something like

```
browser.get('http://localhost:3030/');
browser.waitForAngular();
```

whenever you need to reload your app. It will force the page to be reloaded. But if your app uses `cookie`, you will also need to clean it out in order to make it completely reset.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I was not looking for this. I want a way to reset my App after a spec is completed. Like we have 'onComplete' for `conf.js` files. Similarly, for each `spec.js`.

Comment: like you want to reload the whole app to clear out cache restart it all over again?

Comment: @AmanGupta so far your question is like reset the browser/app, I guessed.  And it is not implemented in protractor https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1645 . But in case you still want to do so. There is a work around way. I will update the answer when I can.

Comment: Yes, you pointed out to the right issue. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: @AmanGupta I have already updated the answer. It is just a work around way. You might need some more tweak if your app use cookies. Otherwise I don't think there's other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The flag named   `restartBrowserBetweenTests` can also be specified in a configuration file. However, this comes with a valid warning from the Protractor team:

> // If [set to] true, protractor will restart the browser between each test.
>   // **CAUTION**: This will cause your tests to *slow down drastically*.

If the speed penalty is of no concern, this could help.

If the above doesn't help and you absolutely want to be sure that the state of the app (and browser!) is clean between specs, you need to roll out your own shellscript which gathers all your `*_spec.js` files and calls `protractor --specs [currentSpec from a spec list/test suite]`.